# Reference f# projects as dlls in another f# project Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, f#

Is it possible to reference a f# projects dll in another if one of the dll is a console app? In order to reference a f# project does it have to be a library type of project?

Comment: Referencing a console application project as a library should work fine.

Comment: This used to occasionally give issues as certain initializers were not called.